# android: activity as dialog: layout_height="wrap_content" but still fullscreen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Is this a good title for a question?

My problem is, I use an activity as a dialog (by not using a fullscreen activity), but even though I use `layout_height="wrap_content"`, the dialog stil uses the whole screen.

Tried using a DialogFragment too, same result.

Here the `.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorDeadBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/setProfileButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/outline_portrait_black_48" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deletePictureButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/outline_delete_black_48" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ShowPicturesActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyPictures" />
```

And here styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyPictures" parent="@style/MyDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" />
```

How can I make the topLinearLayout to wrap_content in height?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the fixed height to recycler view wrap content not work in this case as it expands as an item in your adapter increases better use constraint layout and bind recyclerview constraints from top and bottom and set height to 0dp
simply try yourself set height to wrap_content on reyclerview and use

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:listitem="@layout/your_layout"
tools:itemCount="10"
```

Comment: This didn't help me at all, but maybe I just didn't understand the answer? Could you say it again in a few different words, using punctuation please?